# Compilation error: not found: value nonEmptyText in Play framework while using Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

This is my Application.Scala

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.mvc._



import _root_.scala.xml.Text


object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Redirect(routes.Application.tasks)
  }


  def deleteTask(id: Long) = TODO

  val taskForm = Form(
  "label" -> nonEmptyText
)
def tasks = Action {
  Ok(views.html.index(Task.all(), taskForm))
}

  def newTask = Action { implicit request =>
  taskForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    errors => BadRequest(views.html.index(Task.all(), errors)),
    label => {
      Task.create(label)
      Redirect(routes.Application.tasks)
    }
  )
}
}
```

I'm using play 2.0 framework. Where am I going wrong to get such an error?

Comment: I don't know play, but from your example, where do you expect `nonEmptyText` to come from? It certainly isn't defined anywhere in that code fragment. Perhaps [`Forms.nonEmptyText`](http://osdir.com/ml/play-framework/2012-05/msg02003.html)?

Comment: I thought this import _root_.scala.xml.Text took care of that. How to go about it? Newbie to Scala.

Comment: Looks as if it is defined in play.api.data.Forms: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Forms.scala

Comment: An import `xml.Text` will just do that -- import `Text`. If `nonEmptyText` _was_ inside singleton object `Text`, you could additionally `import Text._`; but there is none. See the other comment, a quick google shows that probably you want `Forms.nonEmptyText`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can browse Play 2 docs [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/scala/index.html). By looking at the index I found that `nonEmptyText` is contained in [play.api.data.Forms](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Forms$) object.

So, you need to either add `import play.api.data.Forms._` as already suggested or replace the current not found symbol with `Forms.nonEmptyText` since it's already imported.

Answer (score 0):

I found that restarting the server solved the issue for me.